# Jquery check multiple Selects have value set

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select

I have a form with multiple select fields allowing you to select multiple entries per select.

Each select is named `id1[]`, `id2[]`, `id3[]` etc.

With Jquery when trying to submit the form can I check if any of the selects haven't had anything selected ?

I've tried this, but the form still submits.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
        $("select[name^='id']:visible").each(function(index, element) {
            if ($(this).val() == "") return false; 
        });
});
```

I don't need to know which specific 'id' select hasn't had an option selected, but it would be nice if I did..

Thanks

Comment: return ($("select[name^='id']:visible > option[value='']:selected").length <= 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to return all selects that have no value selected

```
var selectsWithNoValue = $("select[name^='id']:visible").filter(function() {
     return !this.value.length;
});
```

Then you can just check the length to see if you have any with no value - and you also have access to those elements

```
if(selectsWithNoValue.length) { // if there are selects with no value
    //do something
}
```

Also since you're working with a form bind to the submit handler of the form so instead of the click of a button.

So if you want to prevent the form submit you can do

```
return !selectsWithNoValue.length
```

Which will return false if there are any selects with no value

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qyc2cp58/)

Comment: Thanks - this works well. is there anyway it can display an alert if a select is blank. also could it be expanded to include another select called 'file' ?

Comment: I've removed the name from the select and now it's checking all selects.. which works OK. Would be nice to see if I can get it to show and alert and possibly if is the ID or File select that hasn't been completed..

Comment: :) this seems to work `if (!this.value.length) alert ('All Form Fields Need To Be Completed' + this.name);` added before the first return..

Comment: I've opened a new question to see about making the alerting a bit more noticeable..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304636/flash-nearest-div-based-on-id

Answer (score 2):

Attach the code to form submit handler instead of submit button's click handler, so you can prevent the form from being submitted.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var rtn = true;
    $("select[name^='id']:visible").each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            console.log(this.id); // id
            rtn = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return rtn;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For some reason for me it's still submitting.
My forms name and id is 'form'.. I'll create a fiddle and try it.

Comment: @Rocket yeah gimme the link