# Animating invalid element's nearest divs upon form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, closest

I've the following code, which selects the `<select>` elements which are not selected and prevents the form submission, if any.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
   var count = 0;
   var selectsWithNoValue = $("select:visible").filter(function() {
         if (!this.value.length) {
            sel = this.name;   
            if (count == 0) { alert ('Error ' + sel); ++count;}
         }
     return !this.value.length;
    });
    return !selectsWithNoValue.length;
});
```

Full code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyc2cp58/1/)

---

Is it possible to find the nearest `<div>` to the unselected `<select>` and 'flash' (*could be a couple of quick flashes, or highlighting until the user clicks within the `<div>`*) that to alert the user which entry they should be amending..?

I have tried:

```
$(this).closest("div").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Using this code doesn't work - The required `<div>`doesn't flash and this code causes the form to submit even if the selects are not set.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: If you want to stop the form from submitting, you would need to `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` from the function that checks your form on submit.

Comment: Hi The form doesn't submit if any of the selects are not set. That works fine. It's finding the nearest DIV and highlighting that I'm struggling with.. Thx

Comment: Then why did you say: `... and the form submitted even if the select values were blank.`

Comment: Sorry - I'll update my question. I've worded it badly.

Comment: As a side note, you're not closing many `<p>` and `<select>` tags...

Comment: Question updated. Hopefully that makes more sense !

Comment: @TJ Bad cut and paste.. My live code is closing the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CSS animation like the following:

```
.highlight {
  animation: blink 1s linear 3;
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 #000;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;
  }
}
```

By using the following script:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
  $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
  var selectsWithNoValue = $("select:visible").filter(function () {
    return !this.value;
  }).closest('div').addClass("highlight");
  return !selectsWithNoValue.length;
});
```

---

```js
$("form").submit(function () {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    var selectsWithNoValue = $("select:visible").filter(function () {
        return !this.value;
    }).closest('div').addClass("highlight");
    return !selectsWithNoValue.length;
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s linear 3;
    -ms-animation: blink 1s linear 3;
    -moz-animation: blink 1s linear 3;
    animation: blink 1s linear 3;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 red;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes blink {
    from {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 red;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 red;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 red;
    }
}
@keyframes blink {
    from {
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow:0 0 0px 0 #000;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;
    }
}
div{
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form" name="form">
    <div> <span><b>1</b></span>

        <br/>Select:
        <br/>
        <select name='id1[]' multiple>
            <option value='000'>000</option>
            <option value='001'>001</option>
            <option value='002'>002</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div> <span><b>2</b></span>

        <br/>Select:
        <br/>
        <select name='id2[]' multiple>
            <option value='000'>000</option>
            <option value='001'>001</option>
            <option value='002'>002</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />
        <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Save' />
    </p>
</form>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyc2cp58/4/)

Comment: this works but on only the first submission attempt. Load the page with no select options selected and click Save. You get the alert for id1[] and all three selects flash. Select an option in a select and click Save. You get the alert but no DIV are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

If the ".closest()" method is not working you could try ".next()" and ".prev()". As a parameter you could pass the class of the div (like ' .next(".class") '.

If the animation is not working you could use ".fadeTo()" in a recursive function:

```
function Glow(target, opacity)
{
    function Glow(target, opacity)
    {
        $(target).fadeTo(500, opacity);
        if(opacity == 0.5)
            Glow(target, 1);
        else
            Glow(target, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!